# Import a file that is located in one of three directories?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

## Import a file that could be in one of three directories

I want to import a file called `image.png`. I know it is either in `dir1`, `dir2` or `dir3`

[image]

On unix I can easily open it using a Kleene star.

```
xdg-open ~/dirA/*/image.png
```

On mathematica I tried to add a Kleene star to the `Import` argument string.

```
 Import[$HomeDirectory <> "/dirA/*/image.png"]
```

But this does not work.

### Question:

> How to import a file that is in $1$ of $n$ directories?

Comment: comment to my future self: `FileNames["image.png", {$HomeDirectory}, Infinity]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `dir1`, `dir2`, etc are strings representing the directories, use

```
file = First[FileNames["image.png", {dir1, dir2, dir3}], $Failed]
```

The 2- and 3-argument forms of [`FileNames`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNames.html) are pretty useful.  If the $dir_i$ all live in the same parent directory, then you could use

```
file = First[FileNames["image.png", {parentDir}, 2], $Failed]
```

Comment: Interestingly `FileNames` will accept the Kleene star because it looks for files matching a string pattern. so `FileNames[$HomeDirectory <> "/dirA/*/image.png"]` works too!